# jQuery + Ajax form submission: scrape and store data from form, forward onto action - HOW TO?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that collects information from the user:
I want to keep part of this information and forward the form onto the action with the rest of the information.

My FORM:

```
<form id="my_form" action="http://place_this_should_submit_after_ajax.com" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_url" id="post_url" value="url_ajax_call_will_post_data_to">
    <input type="text" name="name_val" id="name_val">
    <input type="text" name="email_val" id="email_val">
    <input type="text" name="amount_val" id="amount_val">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="praying to god">
</form>
```

My JQUERY:

```
$(function() {

    $("#my_form").submit( function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        name = $("#name_val").val();
        email = $("#email_val").val();
        amount = $("#amount_val").val(); // data form.ACTION will need this info

        // Validate form field values...

        if (validation form field errors) {
            // do error stuff...
        } else {

            // the place I want to send data before posting form to "form.ACTION"
            var post_url = $("#post_url").val();

            // ALL of the data on the form that my #post_url will scrape and store
            var post_data = form.serialize();

            // post the form data to the post_url to collect data out of post_data
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : post_url,
                data : post_data});

            // My pathetic attempt to tell the form to go to form.ACTION
            return true;



        }
    });
}
```

EDIT 1:

Right now the form posts to the ajax call, runs the page there successfully, but doesn't post the page to the form.ACTION (http://place_this_should_submit_after_ajax.com).
This is the intended result of this page.

EDIT 2:

Although I've checked the solution submitted by @Jasen it wasn't a full working solution.  However, it did solve the issue 95%.  The remaining issue was corrected by getting the form data which wouldn't have been submitted on a button.CLICK.

```
extended from the solution submitted by @Jasen

<form id="my_form" ...>
    ...
    <button class="submit-btn">praying to god</button>
</form>

// Correct way to instantiate a button.CLICK
$(".submit-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // THIS IS REQUIRED TO GET THE DATA FROM THE FORM GIVEN THE FORM ISN'T SUBMITTED VIA A BUTTON.CLICK
    var post_data = $("#my_form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: post_url,
        data: post_data
    })
    .done(function(result) {
       $("#my_form").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you expect to happen? What isn't working?

Comment: What's with `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: I expect the data from the form to post via ajax to "post_url" to return successfully from that ajax call and then post the page with form data to and then post to the form.ACTION (http://place_this_should_submit_after_ajax.com)

Comment: [e.preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying `preventDefault` contradicts `return true` so your form will never submit in the default manner.

```
$("#my_form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: post_url,
        data: post_data
    })
    .done(function(result) {
       // if your form submission relies on the ajax result
       // you should do the second post in a callback
       $("#my_form").submit();
    });
});
```

**Edit**

There's a problem with the above that I missed -- The submit handler performs another submit and you could end up in a loop.

Instead, hook into a button's click event.

```
<form id="my_form" ...>
    ...
    <button class="submit-btn">praying to god</button>
</form>

$(".submit-btn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: post_url,
        data: post_data
    })
    .done(function(result) {
       $("#my_form").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I removed preventDefault and it seems to work.  Came here to report this.

However, I think I'll implement your method and see if it works.  If your method does work I'll submit as solution.  Thanks for the response.  Please hold.

Comment: After several attempts to confirm removing preventDefault works it has not.  Still testing.

Comment: The `button` example doesn't work without `preventDefault()`? The button may be picked up as the default submit initiator and you may need preventDefault.

Comment: you're correct.  In addition to adding preventDefault to have the button solution work, I needed to add getting the form data without a form submission.

I'm checking this as a solution as it was the closest to the actual solution and it got me 95% of the way there.

Check my original question for the solution, but I am checking this one for credit.

Comment: I submitted an edit to my original question with my solution which was a combination of yours + my own.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove the `e.preventDefault();`. That stops the default action of the form's submit method from happening.